# ¿Como pasar datos que un servlet obtiene de una BD a una pagina HTML? no JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, servlets

esto es mas una duda de algo que pueda ser factible realizar.

Lo que quiero realizar en si, es que desde un servlet me comunico con mysql para obtener los resultados de una tabla, y quiero pasar esos datos obtenidos a una tabla en una pagina html, se que se puede fácil utilizando JSP, pero quisiera saber si existe, alguna otra forma de poder hacer eso.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

sí que podrías utilizando ajax. Esto te llevaría más tiempo pero podrías hacerlo en JavaScript, lo cual te permite rellenar la tabla con datos de la base de datos sin tener que refrescar la página. (Aquí)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600827/jquery-ajax-call-to-servlet-get-data-as-json] tienes un enlace que te explica bien como hacerlo en JQuery, el procedimiento es bastante simple:
Creas un Servlet que acceda a los datos que quieres enseñar de la base de datos y los conviertes a Json, lo metes en una JsonArray y los imprimes en la pantalla. Aquí ya tienes el servlet creado.
Por otro lado tienes la página con Jquery, la cual llama a tu servlet asíncronamente y obtiene sus datos. lo siguiente sería rellenar la tabla que te interese mediante DOM.